# QML Button text cannot display utf-8 Chinese (only show empty spaces)

Tags: android, qt, utf-8, character-encoding, qml

I'm developing a cross-platform app with **Qt 5.9** (+ V-Play) for our coworking space in Taiwan.
All of users are *Traditional Chinese* native, so I'm using UTF-8 Chinese strings in my app.

Most of the parts seems ok, but the **QML Button** with **UTF-8 Chinese** only show me **empty** spaces.

*On Desktop it works fine*, but *on Android* (both in emulator and on phone) *the problem occured*.
And, if I set the *button.text = "中文 UTF-8 Chinese"* again later in Component.onComplete, it display correctly.

Can I use Chinese (UTF-8) strings in the Button.text field?
If yes, what should I do to make it work?

**Update:**
This only happens at the first tab (the tab shown when App start)
POC in comment

Codes:

```
// imports
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
//import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import QtPositioning 5.2
```

```js
// QML Button parts

Rectangle {
    id: containerBtn
    height: dp(60)
    radius: 5
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    border.color: "blue"


    Button {
        id: btn_reload_pic
        text: "截圖.reload()"
        //dropShadow: true
        //icon: IconType.recycle
        anchors.right: parent.horizontalCenter
        //width: parent.width / 4
        //radius: 5

        onClicked: {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            currentSnapshot.snapshotURL = currentSnapshot.snapshotURL + "?t=" + currentTime
        }
    }

    AppButton {
        id: btnLock
        text: "芝麻開門（或關門）"
        dropShadow: true
        icon: IconType.question
        anchors.left: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width / 4
        radius: 5

        onClicked: lockSwitch()
    }
}
```

```js
// Component.onComplete
btnLock.text = '芝麻關門';
```

Screenshots:

[Button shows empty utf-8 chinese string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JLlr.png)

[after setting button.text later in onComplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFSf4.png)

Environments:

Qt 5.9
QtCreator 4.3.0
V-Play 2.12.1-1
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit
Android 7.0 API 24, x86 emulator / HTC 10

Test App: MOLiApp on Google Play (I cannot post link here)

Comment: POC here: https://github.com/BlueT/qt-testing-utf8

Comment: According to some tests from other developers, Android 5 works fine, so this might be Android 7 compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *bug* still *under investigate*.

As in my test, the issue only happens in the first-ever loaded page, so a **workaround** from [V-Play forum](https://v-play.net/developers/forums/t/qml-button-text-cannot-display-utf-8-chinese-only-show-empty-spaces#post-16697) is to postpone the loading process with **Loader**.

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.5

App {
  id: app

  // loads the given item dynamically after app-start
  Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: navigationComponent
    asynchronous: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false

    // after loading is finished, add the item to the main app content item
    onLoaded: loader.item.parent = app.contentItem
  }

  // component for main navigation
  Component {
    id: navigationComponent
    Navigation {

      // Comment to use a navigation drawer instead of tabs on Android
      navigationMode: navigationModeTabs

      NavigationItem {
        title: qsTr("First Page")
        icon: IconType.square

        FirstPage {}
      }

      NavigationItem {
        title: qsTr("Second Page")
        icon: IconType.circle

        SecondPage {}
      }

    }
  }
}
```

This is not a fix but a working workaround.